# NUnit Pass variable from [Test] to [TearDown]

Tags: c#, nunit

I need to pass the variable that contains Guid to the TearDown method. Something like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        ...
        var myVariable = $"Test-{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        ...
    }
```

So, I need to pass this 'myVariable' to the TearDown:

```
    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        ...
        DoSomethingWith(myVariable);
        ...
    }
```

I tried to set the Category for my Test, but it does not work with Guid
Also I tried to figure out how to parse myVariable from TestContext.CurrentContext... obj, but wasn't success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a field instead of a variable.

```cs
class MyTest
{
    string? myField = null;

    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        ...
        myField = $"Test-{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        ...
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        ...
        DoSomethingWith(myField);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work provided none of the tests are parallelizable. If any tests run in parallel, they are sharing the same variable. Even if they are not currently running that way, someone may come along in the future and add the `ParallelizableAttribute`.

Comment: @Charlie if the field is used by one test only, there is no issue. If we need to store and do something with strings from multiple tests, we can use `ConcurrentBag`. There is always a way.

Comment: True, but that limitation isn't part of the OP's question. _In general_ changing state of the fixture makes the test non-parallelizable. In particular cases, of course, one can work around that but it's not very robust.

Comment: @Charlie not sure I understand your point. In my experience, it is very common to use `[TearDown]` for resource cleanup, DB state restore, etc. If this requires some state from tests (e.g. ids of inserted rows), then use a field. When parallelization is involved, use thread-safe collections or some form of per-test state separation. It is as robust as you make it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. You obviously know what you're doing. I said _in general_ meaning it's not good advice for everyone. That was because your answer doesn't tell those folks about all they have to do to allow running in parallel. My experience in answering questions is that the majority of users assume that NUnit sees `[Parallelizable]` and makes sure there is no conflict, which is why I commented.